# How do I read a plist?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios4, plist

I have a plist that is binary plist.

Do i need to convert it before I can use it? or can my application read the plist?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It can understand binary plists.

**Edit:**

As Peter Hosey points out, this will only work if the root element is a dictionary. If the root element is an array, you can use `+[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:]`.

Comment: This will only work for plist files whose root element is a dictionary.

Comment: My root element is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A much more general solution is to use NSPropertyListSerialization, as suggested by Vladimir in his answer that he deleted. It both serializes (makes plist data from an object) and deserializes (re-creates an object tree from plist data).

It is always able to parse any valid plist, binary or otherwise, regardless of the type of the root element; you may then want to inspect the object it returns to make sure it's of a type you expect.

Comment: WHats the difference between your solution and +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:]

Comment: Defender Of The Code: As I mentioned in my comment on mipadi's answer, `dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:` will only return a dictionary; pass it a plist file containing some other kind of object at its root, and it will return `nil`. NSPropertyListSerialization will return whatever is in the file. This enables you to support different types, such as a single dictionary or an array of dictionaries.